# Functor for scala.collection.Map[Int, T]

Tags: scala, dictionary, functor

I am trying to find information if it is possible to create a `Functor` for a `Map` type.
The docs have information for the `List`, `Option`, but not for my case.

Can you please tell me if it is possible to create a `Functor[Map[Int, T]]`?

Below I will attach an implementation of a similar functor for a `List`.

```
trait Functor[F[_]]:
    def map[A, B](list: F[A])(f: A => B): F[B]

given Functor[List] with
    def map[A, B](list: List[A])(f: A => B): List[B] = ???
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible; as proof it is possible, you can see that both **cats** and _(old)_ **Scalaz** provides it. Does that answer your question? - _(Bonus?)_ look for `partial unification` and type lambdas.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez, I searched there but couldn't find. could you please show a piece of code for my case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- `Map[A, B]` is almost the same as `A => B`, but with a finite domain.
- `A => B` is basically the `Reader[A, B]`
- `Reader[A, B]` is a monad
- All monads are functors

So, yes let's try to do the same as what `Reader` does: it simply post-composes the functions given to `map`:

```
given mapFunctor[K]: Functor[[V] =>> Map[K, V]] with
  def map[A, B](m: Map[K, A])(f: A => B): Map[K, B] = m.view.mapValues(f).toMap
```

The `toMap` is necessary, because `mapValues` is non-strict (it refuses to map all the values right away, and keeps the function composition in a symbolic `MapView`).

Comment: What does this "=>>" mean?

Comment: The `F[_]` is expected to have one type-hole, but the `Map` has two (one for keys, one for values). We have to partially apply the `K` parameter in order to obtain a type constructor with the right kind. The `=>>` is a type lambda: it's doing essentially the same as the expression `(v) => m(k, v)`, but on type-level; In 2.13, one would usually have written `Map[K, ?]` with *kind-projector* plugin, but it's no longer needed in 3.x

Answer (score 5):

Expanding Luis' and Andrey's answers, with Scala 2 and scala-cats try using type alias

```
import cats.Functor

type MapInt[T] = Map[Int, T]
Functor[MapInt].map(Map(1 -> "woo"))(a => a + "hoo") 
// : MapInt[String] = Map(1 -> "woohoo")
```

or using Scala 2 type lambda ["atrocity"](https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/issues/2041#issuecomment-283075876)

```
Functor[({type MapInt[T]=Map[Int, T]})#MapInt].map(Map(1 -> "woo"))(a => a + "hoo")
// : MapInt[String] = Map(1 -> "woohoo")
```

or using [kind-projector](https://github.com/typelevel/kind-projector)

```
Functor[Map[Int, *]].map(Map(1 -> "woo"))(a => a + "hoo")
// : MapInt[String] = Map(1 -> "woohoo")
```

[scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/uOkBsgEtQyuouvLxlPE0Fg)

---

Regarding `Map` being of wrong "kind" for `Functor` try using the REPL to explore the idea (if you start with `sbt console` it should load it with all the dependencies from `build.sbt`):

```
scala> import cats.Functor
import cats.Functor

scala> :kind -v Functor
cats.Functor's kind is X[F[A]]
(* -> *) -> *
This is a type constructor that takes type constructor(s): a higher-kinded type.

scala> :kind -v Map
Map's kind is F[A1,+A2]
* -> * -(+)-> *
This is a type constructor: a 1st-order-kinded type.

scala> type MapInt[T] = Map[Int, T]
type MapInt

scala> :kind -v MapInt
MapInt's kind is F[A]
* -> *
This is a type constructor: a 1st-order-kinded type.
```

Note how `Functor` has higher-order kind

```
(* -> *) -> *
\______/
   |
required shape of type argument to Functor
```

which means it expects a type constructor of first-order kind, and in particular a type constructor which takes a single type argument

```
* -> *
|
only one type argument expected
```

Now `Map` type constructor by itself does have first-order kind expected by `Functor`, however it is of wrong *arity* as it takes two type arguments instead of one

```
1st arg to Map
|
* -> * --> *
     |
   2nd arg to Map
```

hence we need a type lambda to fix the first type parameter of `Map` to `Int` whilst keeping second type parameter free which turns it into a type constructor of the correct kind and arity for `Functor`

```
scala> :kind -v MapInt
MapInt's kind is F[A]
* -> *
```

Here is an example of a higher-order type constructor which takes another binary-arity first-order type constructor as its type argument

```
trait Foo[F[A, B]]
```

Let's check if `Map` now fits without having to use a type lambda

```
scala> trait Foo[F[A, B]]
trait Foo

scala> :kind -v Foo
Foo's kind is X[F[A1,A2]]
(* -> * -> *) -> *
This is a type constructor that takes type constructor(s): a higher-kinded type.

scala> new Foo[Map] {}
val res2: Foo[Map] = $anon$1@589af27e
```

Comment: Oh, interesting. Kind-projector deprecated the `?`-syntax, and now uses `*` instead. Hm, I used to alias `* = Nothing`, that seemed occasionally useful as argument for covariant type constructors...

Comment: @AndreyTyukin It is in preparation for Scala 3 eventually replacing existential wildcard `_` with `?`, I think targeted for 3.2 release.